# How do I access a specific value from my Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed a Youtube video on accessing a specific value from my database, this is exactly what the video had (except I changed it to my values). When their app ran, it made a toast with the corresponding value(s). When I start mine I get the error "Unfortunately, App has stopped." Am I doing something wrong or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    test = database.getReference("https://matts-macros.firebaseio.com/values");
    test.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value: + " + data.get("adjustedcarbs"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image: database values]

Comment: If you check the console log in android studio you will see the error. Can you print it here?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.langString" on the line of my toast

Comment: I've been treating my values as if they were strings and not longs. Simply changing Map<String,String> to Map<Long,Long> fixed my problem.

Comment: The right wat is to treat your objects as Map<String, Object>, checkout my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the reference in a wrong way. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)). You should do one of two things:

1) Replace this:

```
test = database.getReference("https://matts-macros.firebaseio.com/values");
```

with this:

```
test = database.getReference().child("values");
```

2) If you want to use your url, you should do this instead:

```
String myUrl = "https://matts-macros.firebaseio.com/values";
test = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(myUrl);
```

Regarding your parsing error, try with a `Map<String,Object>` :

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

Comment: Well spotted Levi! Thanks for helping a fellow Firebase developer!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was also treating my values as strings and not longs, which caused it to close out my application.

Comment: yeah, it always gets me too :)